# Bash script to loop through directories and remove some content

Tags: bash, shell, console

I'm trying to write a bash script that will loop through directories that contain some other directories, remove most of them and their content, and in one case, remove all the files and directories inside except for the one with most recent modification date. This is the directory structure:

```
> 0001_Job_X
    > fonts
    > images
    > MS Documents
    > Design Files
    > Web Files

> 0002_Job_Y
    > fonts
    > images
    > MS Documents
    > Design Files
    > Web Files
```

and so on... (there's a lot of them). My goal is to remove fonts, MS Documents and Web Files and ideally, to remove all the content of Design Files except one file that has the most recent modification date.

This is the script that I've managed to write so far:

```
for d in ./*; do
cd "$d"
rm -rf ./fonts
rm -rf ./MS\ Documents
rm -rf ./Web\ Files
cd ..
done
```

Which works, but I can't figure out how to remove all the contents of Design Files except for the one file that has the most recent modification date. Could someone help me please? Thanks!

Comment: Is it guaranteed that there are only **files** in Design Files? I mean there are no directories in it, right?

Comment: There might be some directories there but I'm only interested in keeping one file that is always in top level of Design Files directory. All the directories there can be removed without checking anything.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet will find the latest file in a folder (Design Files) - ignoring sub folders, and remove all other files.

```
FOLDER='Design Files'
    # Name of latest "real" file - exclude folders
FILES=$(find $FOLDER -maxdepth 1 -type f)
    # Find the last modified
LATEST=$(ls -t $FILES)
    # Find all files other than last modified
OLDER_FILES=$(ls $FILES | grep -v "^$LATEST$")
rm -f $OLDER_FILES
```